# I want to encrypt all the files in the test folder

Tags: c++, cryptography, aes, crypto++

I want to encrypt all the files in the test folder.
This works successfully for text files, but not for binaries.

Source Code:

```
void l(string& foldername, vector<string>& output) {
    DIR* dir;
    struct dirent* DirEntry;

    if ((dir = opendir(foldername.c_str())) != NULL)
    {
        while ((DirEntry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (strcmp(DirEntry->d_name, ".") && strcmp(DirEntry->d_name, ".."))
            {
                string subfolder(foldername);
                subfolder += "\\";
                subfolder += DirEntry->d_name;
                DIR* subdir;
                if ((subdir = opendir(subfolder.c_str())) != NULL)
                {
                    l(subfolder, output);
                    closedir(subdir);
                }
                else
                {
                    string fullname(foldername);
                    fullname = fullname + '\\' + DirEntry->d_name;
                    output.push_back(fullname);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
}

void start() {
    try
    {
        vector <string> volumes;
        volumes.push_back("test\\");
        for (string v : volumes)
        {
            vector<string> o;
            l(v, o);
            for (string en : o)
            {
                SecByteBlock key(AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH + AES::BLOCKSIZE);
                HKDF<SHA256> s256;
                s256.DeriveKey(key, key.size(), (const CryptoPP::byte*)pa.data(), pa.size(), (const CryptoPP::byte*)iv.data(), iv.size(), NULL, 0);
                ifstream file(en, ios::binary);
                std::string t((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
                if (file.is_open())
                {
                    string enc;
                    CTR_Mode<AES>::Encryption ee;
                    ee.SetKeyWithIV(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH, key + AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
                    StringSource encryptor(t.data(), true, new StreamTransformationFilter(ee, new StringSink(enc)));
                    ofstream e(en, ios::binary);
                    e << enc;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}
```

Where is the problem that is not done for binaries?
Please guide me and see where the problem comes from.
Please guide me and see where the problem comes from.

Comment: Try to use `std::vector` instead of `std::string`, treat all files as binary data.

Comment: I tried this but it still didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? This is like calling your car mechanic and describing your problem as "my car doesn't move".

Comment: Are you treating binary files as if they were text files?  Binary is **not** text and treating one as the other will cause problems.